# R DataTable Two FifElse Statement

Tags: r, data.table

```
    data = data.frame("var1" = c("one", "two", "three", "four", NA))



 I seek a data.table fifelse solution so get, 

data = data.frame("var1" = c("one", "two", "three", "four", NA),
"var2" = c(10,20,30,40,NA)
```

The rule is:
if var1 = "one" var2 = "10"

if var1 = "two" var2 = "20"

if var1 = "three" var2 = "30"

if var1 = "four" var2 = "40"

And then I hope to label '10', '20', '30', '40' as : dog, cat, fox bird

So how to use multiple fifelse statement and label variable in data.table

Comment: what is the expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to create 'var2', we can pass a named vector to match and create the new 'var2'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, var2 := setNames(c(10, 20, 30, 40),
        c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'))[as.character(var1)]]
data[, label := setNames(c('dog', 'cat', 'fox', 'bird'), c(10, 20, 30, 40))[as.character(var2)]][]  


data
#    var1 var2 label
#1:   one   10   dog
#2:   two   20   cat
#3: three   30   fox
#4:  four   40  bird
#5:  <NA>   NA  <NA>
```

---

It may be more efficient to do this with a named vector, but `fifelse` can be used as well

```
setDT(data)[, var2 := fifelse(var1 == 'one', 10,
                     fifelse(var1 == 'two', 20,
                     fifelse(var1 == 'three', 30,
                     fifelse(var1 == 'four', 40, NA_real_))))]
```

and similarly, for 'label'

Or in the `devel` version, there is `fcase`

```
setDT(data)[, var2 := fcase(var1 == 'one', 10,
                             var1 == 'two', 20,
                             var1 == 'three', 30,
                             var1 == 'four', 40)]
```

Comment: the rest of my question got cut off I will update @akrun

Comment: the second solution is great. So i combine the 'fifelse' solution and use the last line for the first patch of code for label? Thanks again! I am learning a lot from you

Comment: @bvowe glad to help you.  I also updated with `fcase` from the devel version of data.table